# InfluxDB and Grafana on server without datetime sync

Tags: datetime, raspberry-pi, timezone, grafana, influxdb

I’m running an app on raspberry. This raspberry is not connected to internet, and without RTC. So the raspberry datetime is random.

The app push data to GraphQL. So data are stored to the machine timestamp, witch is a random one.

Grafana is connected to GraphQL to read data.

**Problem :**

Data are stored at the datetime of the serveur, for example *2020-01-01 00h00m00s*
Grafana get the datetime of the browser witch is sync with internet datetime, for example *2020-01-01 14h30m12s*

My device is not connected to internet, but all apps (data producer app / InfluxDB / Grafana) are connected in localhost. The clock on my device is set randomly. It take probably the last known datetime ?

So data are stored at the datetime of device. But Grafana take the datetime of the browser (my phone / my pc) witch theirs datetime have been sync with UTC. When I tried t visualize data on Grafana, they are absent because they are stored at a datetime in the past.

**Question :**

How to say at Grafana to use server datetime and not browser one ?
My problem is not related with problem  where data are store at UTC and Grafana at UTC+1.

Comment: Hi, your question isn't very clear.  GraphQL is a query language, it's not something you can push to.  Also, if your devices aren't connected to anything, how are they pushing data anywhere?  How are the clocks on your Rasberry PI devices set at all?  Manually by the user? Sync'd to something, somehow, somewhere?  Please explain.  Thanks.

Comment: My device is not connected to internet, but all apps (data producer app / InfluxDB / Grafana) are connected in localhost. 
The clock on my device is set randomly. It take probably the last known datetime ?

Comment: So data are stored at the datetime of device.  But Grafana take the datetime of the browser (my phone / my pc) witch theirs datetime have been sync with UTC. When I tried t visualize data on Grafana, they are absent because they are stored at a datetime in the past.